# NoMethodError (undefined method 'aluno' for ActionController:Parameters) - aluno_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reform

I have a class `MatriculaForm` with some associations (belongs_to and has_many):

```ruby
class MatriculaForm < Reform::Form
  property :aluno, form: PessoaForm
  properties :atributos_extras, :mensalidade

  #validation
  validates :aluno, :dia_vencimento, :empresa, presence: true
end
```

And the `_form.html.erb`

```html
<%= form_for @matricula_form do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :aluno do |aluno| %>
        <%= aluno.text_field :nome %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

On controller, I do

```ruby
MatriculaForm.new(params[:matricula])
```

But the `initialize` reform method raise a error:

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `aluno' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fe835772a70> ``

I saw that the parameters become with `aluno_attributes` key name. But reading the docs, thoses parameters names are accepeted.

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to whitelist the attributes for association?

```
association_attributes: [:id .... etc.]
```

When the method error appears it might be that the association is not correct? Did you correctly set up the `belongs_to` and `has_many` 
Does this only happen while validating? Does the form save without validation? I am not sure whether the validation can be done that way. May be you want to use `validates_association`
Please check the docs for correct syntax.

Comment: the attributes already are in the whitelist and yes, the model save correctly without using the reform validation. And I not found docs ref about ```validates_association```

Comment: on controller ```params.require(:matricula).permit(:id, :aluno_attributes => [:id, :nome, etc])```